# What is the Linux equivalent of the windows group policy?

Tags: linux

I have a number of Linux virtual machines which I use for building software.

I am finding that I am having to repeat tasks on several machines such as:

- Removing software
- Updating software
- Adding new tools
- Setting up mappings to the Windows Server
- Setting startup applications
- Altering system wide environment variables

Is there are Linux tool for managing computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend Puppet (http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet/). It's a difficult system to grasp, but can do the job.

For your needs I think it's a correct choice.

If you need to integrate Puppet with VM testing environments, have a look at '[vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/)' .

- Other options for configuration management: Chef, CFEngine.
- Other options for deployment/config management in Cloud Environments: Juju

Answer (score 2):

There are several configuration management software for linux:
- Puppet 
- HP Server Automation
- Chef

I ordered the list using my preferences.